# Customizing the awesome_nested_set default dropdown select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-sets, html-select

I'm using awesome_nested_set to display categories and subcategories. I've used this

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" }, {:include_blank => 'Base Category'},{:class => "form-control"} %>
```

But in this case it adds `-` to show the nested nature of subcategories. I just want to use spaces instead of a `-` hyphens. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'&nbsp;' * i.level} #{i.name}".html_safe }, {:include_blank => 'Base Category'},{:class => "form-control"} %>
```

i put the `& nbsp;` character instead of `-` and set the string as `.html_safe`